# exporting a nested list of numbers and strings to a tab delimited file

Tags: python, export, nested-lists, csv

I'm pretty new to python and I'm just having an issue writing a tab delimited file to a directory on my server. I have a nested list that has around 90 rows and 900 columns.
I would like to write this as a tab delimited file but I don't know how.

Below is a sample list of what my list looks like (only much bigger) after I have modified it with a script:

```
sample_l=open(sample.txt, "r")
```

sample_l was further modified with a complicated script to create sample_mod

```
sample_mod=[['age', 1, 'births', 2], ['cars',3,'foods',4],['set', 10, 'grm', 6]]
```

How can I create a tab delimited text file that looks like this?

$ less sample_mod.txt

```
age 1 births 2

cars 3 foods 4

smoke 10 grams 6
```

I've tried the code below but it's wrong the nested list includes integers and strings:

```
with open('sample.txt', 'w') as file:
file.writelines('\t'.join(i) + '\n' for i in sample_mod)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [csv module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) with the `excel-tab` dialect:

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('sample.txt', 'w') as f:
...   w = csv.writer(f, dialect = 'excel-tab')
...   w.writerows(sample_mod)
...
```

After I ran this code with your `sample_mod` list the file 'sample.txt' contained:

```
age 1   births  2
cars    3   foods   4
set 10  grm 6
```

which is the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) with an appropriate `Dialect`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try converting the integers to strings first. Check out this page: http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/93655